# Why won't Manipulate work with symbols generated by Symbol?

Tags: manipulate, symbols

Suppose I am provided with two data lists.  (Assume for the moment that they are lists of integers.)  I would like a function that generates bar charts that I can manipulate.

Here is what I have:

```
f[dL1_List, dL2_List] :=
  Module[{dL1SymList, dL2SymList},
   dL1SymList = (Symbol["dL1" <> ToString[#]] &) /@ dL1;
   dL2SymList = (Symbol["dL2" <> ToString[#]] &) /@ dL2;
   (
     Manipulate[Grid[{
         {
          BarChart[dL1SymList, PlotLabel -> "dL1"],
          BarChart[dL2SymList, PlotLabel -> "dL2"]
          }
         }], ##] &
     ) @@
    Join[
     MapThread[({{#1, #2}, 0.0, 10*#2} &), {dL1SymList, dL1}],
     MapThread[({{#1, #2}, 0.0, 10*#2} &), {dL2SymList, dL2}]
     ]
   ];

f[Range[1, 5], Range[1, 5]]
```

However, while this does not produce any error, it does not display bar graphs either.  Can you please help me understand where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to get it working: you need to read and fully grok the documentation for `Manipulate`... it explains in detail why constructs like this are used, and the changes in "expected" behaviors within `Manipulate`.

```
f[dL1_List, dL2_List] := 
  Module[{dL1SymList, dL2SymList}, 
   dL1SymList = (Symbol["dL1" <> ToString[#]] &) /@ dL1;
   dL2SymList = (Symbol["dL2" <> ToString[#]] &) /@ dL2;
   (With[{dL1SymList = dL1SymList, dL2SymList = dL2SymList}, 
       Manipulate[
        Grid[{{BarChart[dL1SymList, PlotLabel -> "dL1"], 
           BarChart[dL2SymList, PlotLabel -> "dL2"]}}], ##]] &) @@ 
    Join[MapThread[({{#1, #2}, 0.0, 10*#2} &), {dL1SymList, dL1}], 
     MapThread[({{#1, #2}, 0.0, 10*#2} &), {dL2SymList, dL2}]]];

f[Range[1, 3], Range[1, 2]]
```

[image]